MySQL with TLS connection in NestJS
In my NestJS backend I wanted to add a TLS connection for my database which is in MySQL. My MySQL is on Azure and I have turned off the require_secure_transport = OFF now if I turn on, I get this error:
[Nest] 1  - 04/23/2024, 6:17:10 AM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Connections using insecure transport are prohibited while --require_secure_transport=ON.
Error: Connections using insecure transport are prohibited while --require_secure_transport=ON.
    at Packet.asError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:728:17)
    at ClientHandshake.execute (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:29:26)
    at PoolConnection.handlePacket (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:456:32)
    at PacketParser.onPacket (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:85:12)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:92:25)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:559:12)
    at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:510:3)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:390:5)

My TypeORM configuration is this way:
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      username: 'root',
      password: 'root',
      database: 'test',
      entities: [],
      synchronize: true,
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}


had added the ssl as this way but dint work
import * as fs from 'fs';
const sslOptions = {
ca: fs.readFileSync('/home/testWebsite/certfolder/certificate.crt.pem'),
};
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
@Module({
imports: [
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
type: 'mysql',
host: 'localhost',
port: 3306,
username: 'root',
password: 'root',
database: 'test',
entities: [],
synchronize: true,
ssl:{ ca: sslOptions }
}),
],
})
export class AppModule {}

got the answer:
below synchronize true
just add code as below:
 ssl: { secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_3_method'},
you can change to TLSv1_2_method if you are using 1.2 Tls or if you are using 1.3 Tls then use TLSv1_3_method
finally got it working.
